# Compute the limit for $x \to \infty$ of a certain rational function

Tags: limits

Compute the following limit:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac{9x^8 + 5x^2 − 6}{
3x^8 + 2x^4 + 1}
$$

The answer may be 
A. 2
B. 3
C. 5
D. 7

Comment: It's quite unclear what the function is

Comment: It's really difficult to see what you're taking the limit of.

Comment: Are you talking about
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}9x^8+5x^2-63x^8+2x^4+1?$$

Comment: Did you mean
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{9x^8+5x^2-6}{3x^8+2x^4+1}\;\;\LARGE ?$$

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange.com. Please explain where the problem is coming from and what you have tried so far.

Comment: L'Hopital's rule works. Or just look at the ratio of the coefficients of the highest order terms in the numerator and denominator  (since the highest order is the same in both).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Divide numerator and denominator by $x^8$ to get:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{9+5/x^{6}-6/x^8}{3+2/x^4+1/x^8}$$